# Issues reading from standard input | Strange outputs

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, free

I am taking input from standard input through redirection (< filename). The format of the file is pretty simple, something like this :

```
>SampleText1
ANYRANDOMLETTERSTILLOFUNKNOWNLENGTH
$
ANYRANDOMLETTERSTILLOFUNKNOWNLENGTH
$$
>SampleText2
ANYRANDOMLETTERSTILLOFUNKNOWNLENGTH
$
ANYRANDOMLETTERSTILLOFUNKNOWNLENGTH
$$
$$$
```

**Note: $$$ is end of the file. And the format >text $ >text2 $$ repeats any number of times**

The code I've written for this looks like this:

```
scanf("%c", &noise);
char temp[60];

if (noise == '>' || noise == '<')
{
    fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);
}
char xo;
int flag = 0;

while (1)
{
    char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));

    while (1)
    {
        if (fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin) == NULL)
        {
            flag = 2;
            break;
        }
        else if (temp[0] == '>')
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            strtok(temp, "\n");
            strcat(str, temp);
        }
    }
    char *str1 = strtok(str, "$");
    char *str2 = strtok(NULL, "$");

    if (!str2)
        str2 = "";
    puts(str1);
    printf("\n \n");
    puts(str2);
    printf("\n \n");
    callAFunction(str1, str2);
    // for (i=0; i<strlen(str);i++)
    // free(str[i]);
    // free(str);
    str[0] = '\0';
    if (flag == 2)
        break;
    else
        fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), stdin);
}
```

My task is to take values before $ and $$ in 2 different strings and pass them into a function and then proceed. I am getting strange outputs. My guess is that problem is with clearing str. Help please, near a deadline :(

Comment: Do you realize that `malloc(sizeof(char));` will alloocate a buffer only 1 byte long? That's going to be a big problem.

Comment: I know. That was sort of intentional and trivial because in the end I am doing strcat which will do the task.

Comment: No, `strcat` doesn't allocate memory for you.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that needs to change:

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Only allocates one byte of space for `str`. That will cause memory overwrites you don't want (e.g., from `strcat(str, temp);` According to `man strcat`:

> The  strcat()  function  appends the src string to the dest string,
>   overwriting the terminating null byte ('\0') at the end of dest, and
>   then adds a terminating null byte.  The strings may not overlap, and
>   **the dest string must have enough space for the result.**

You want something much longer, even longer than `temp` (judging from the code). So figure out how big that needs to be and replace it with:

```
char *str = malloc(SIZE_I_NEED);
```

Comment: Each line is of 60 characters so allocated str>temp = 70 size but the issue is also that things from previous read is coming along, its not sort of flushing.

For e.g.
>pair1
abcef
$
asd
$$
>pair2
lkjh
$
poiu
$$
$$$

The output is for str1 is like:cdeflkjh

Why so? :o

Comment: You'll need to figure out how much space you need for `str`. As it stands, the code you show will have unexpected/unpredictable behavior since it will overwrite the buffer you have allocated.

Comment: Between >pair1 and $ there are numerous lines, each of 60 characters. So, in each scan do I need to do realloc?

Comment: You could do `realloc` to solve the problem per line. Also, don't forget to account for the needed null terminator when allocating space.

Comment: It should be part of standard lib. Check for typos. Show exactly what error you're getting. Also, another approach would be not to use `strcat` and `realloc` but, instead, create a list of strings. Your algorithm works to paste all the strings together only to break them apart again using `strtok`. Why not create a list (array) of strings, then they're already separate?

Comment: **The error**: * glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x09fb0008 ***

Comment: The modification I did is:
 `strtok(temp, "\n");
   str = (char*) realloc (str, sizeof(char)*60); 
   strcat (str, temp);`

Comment: That `realloc` error means some other part of your code corrupted the heap (where the memory is allocated from). Is `60` long enough for every line you read in? And then you need to allocate 1 more byte than whatever that maximum is. Check for other areas in your code where you might be overwriting. Also, as an aside, don't typecast `realloc` and `malloc`. Do `str = realloc(str, 60*sizeof(char));`.